# Using pipe in combination with *ngIf and Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Attempting to show a template until the posts Observable is ready:

```
    <ng-template #loading>
        <div>Loading...</div>
    </ng-template>

    <div *ngIf="posts | async else loading">
    {{ posts | json }}
    </div>
```

When the posts Observable is set, the `posts | json` renders like this:

```
    { "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": true, "value": [ { "title": "Simulating HTTP Requsts", "content": "This is off the hook!!" } ] }, "operator": { "delay": 3000, "scheduler": { "actions": [], "active": false } } }
```

How do we get it to render just the value that we would normally get via `posts | async`?

I tried `posts | async | json` but that renders `null` first and then 3 seconds later it renders the value.

[This is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loading-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<div *ngIf="posts | async as postsSync; else loading">
    {{ postsSync| json }}
 </div>
```

You basically want to bind the "unwrapped" value of the observable to a template variable, which can be done in this manner.